# How do I stop a javascript animation from happening repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a script that changes the class of some elements from "hidden" to "show" in order to add a cool "visible on scroll" effect. The issue is, after the page loads and the page has been scrolled the animations happen again when scrolling back up making it look clunky, and to make it worse if an element borders the visible/non-visible section of the screen it has a spasm that loops the animation constantly.

This is the current script :

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    console.log(entry);
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.classList.add("show");
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.remove("show");
    }
  });
});

const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden");
hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));
```

How do I make this happen just once and get rid of the junky spasms? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note that java and javascript are two different languages. I've updated your question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`unobserve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/unobserve) your elements:

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    console.log(entry);
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.classList.add("show");
      //this stops the observer on the intersecting element:
      observer.unobserve(entry.target);
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.remove("show");
    }
  });
});

const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden");
hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried what you said and it pretty much broke the page lol. Half of the content disappeared and the other issues were not resolved. : \

Comment: Well I switched some of your code and thought it worked but it was still broken on the mobile view. I added your change into an else if instead of leaving it inside of the original if. Which worked until I tested the responsive views and the elements would jump around when they were barely in view. SOOOO close.

Comment: Update:  If I enter your code into the console in the dev tools everything works...running the same code on my editor however, breaks the site. Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: @DaltonMowrey Sorry, it's `entry.target`, please check the edit: `observer.unobserve(entry.target);`.

Comment: Right on! That works MUCH better now. Thanks so much!